# Jquery change class still keeps function

Tags: jquery

I have a menu on my page that has some *jquery* animations attached to each button. I am in the process of making the site responsive and would like to remove all *Jquery* animations when the window is resized and add in a separate CSS3 animation (for better mobile performance).

The way i am trying to switch functions on the buttons is by removing the desktop class associated with that button and add in a mobile class hence removing any *jquery* functions associated in the desktop class and adding in the css3 functions in the mobile class.

Here is my code so far:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 900) {
    $(".aboutbutton").toggleClass("aboutbuttondesktop");
  }
});
```

So when i successfully remove the desktop class the `.animate` functions still remain. How can i remove the class and handlers on this + add it my new class and handlers? Have had a search round and some documentation on propagation but

1. I am not sure if this is the issue and
2. couldn't successfully implement the stop propagation code.

   ```
    $('.aboutbutton').on("click", ".aboutbutton", function () {

       $(".arrow-up").animate({
           borderBottomColor: "rgb(37,164,171)"
       },850);

    $(".topnavi").animate({
           "background-color": "rgb(37,164,171)"
       },850);


                   $(".headercurrent").animate({
                     "margin-left":"147px",
                     "background-color": "rgb(37,164,171)", 
                    width: 92

                   },850,"easeInOutQuint");

       $('.homecontainer,.aboutcontainer,.contactcontainer,.musiccontainer,.portfoliocontainer,.backgroundimage').removeClass('elementhovered');       


       $(".backgroundimage").fadeOut(800);
       setTimeout(function () {
           $(".backgroundimage").fadeIn(800);
           }, 800);


       setTimeout(function () {
       $('.backgroundimage').css({
           "background-image": "url(Aboutmeblur.jpg)",
               'background-size': "cover"
       });
       $('.backgroundimage').css({
           "background-repeat": "no-repeat"
       });
       }, 800);
       //fades unwanted pages
       $('.homecontainer,.musiccontainer, .portfoliocontainer, .contactcontainer').fadeOut({
           queue: false,
           duration: 700
       });

       //animates up unwanted pages
       $('.homecontainer, .musiccontainer, .portfoliocontainer, .contactcontainer').animate({
           'margin-Top': "-1000px"
       }, 400, 'easeInBack');

       //brings in selected page with a 0.7 second pause       
       setTimeout(function () {
           $('.aboutcontainer ').fadeIn({
               queue: false,
               duration: 100
           });
           $(".aboutcontainer").animate({
               marginTop: "115px"
           }, 1200, 'easeOutQuint');
       }, 700);
   });

   $('.aboutbutton').one("click", function () {
       setTimeout(function () {
           $(".aboutcontainer").load("about.php");
       }, 1200);
   });
   ```

Comment: Removing class does nothing if you bind events directly via `$('.class').click` for example. You need to do event delegation like this `$('body').on('click', '.class')`. Then removing a class does the trick.

Comment: We need to see how you're attaching your events to `.aboutbutton`. You probably need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as @TwiStar proposes

Comment: Your function 'toggles' the class per your condition.. thats not right... I.E you could resize your window while your condition is still true..

Comment: 1 other thing, could you explain the logic of trading js anims for css anims.. why not just go css anims all the way?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the responses. wanted ie 9 compatability hency the jquery. Lets say i use removeClass and addClass instead (which is what i think i was using when i got the class to remove successfully) I've updated the code above to include the jqueyr im using on that one button

Comment: @TwiStar I also tried changing my .click handler to $(".aboutbutton").on("click", ".aboutbutton", function..... but no luck

Comment: Doing it wrong again. Event delegation works from parent to children, so it's like `$('.about-button-wrapper').on('click', '.about-button')`.

Comment: Not sure i follow, sorry still getting my head around this. Could you tell me how I would implement the .on function with context of my current HTML. Site link: http://benliger.webatu.com/

Comment: some good documentation here but still struggling to see how i can apply it to my code: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [delegated event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) should look more like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".aboutbutton", function(){
    //...
});
```

And your resize event should be rephrased to replace the classes accordingly:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 900) {
      $(".aboutbutton").removeClass("aboutbutton").addClass("aboutbuttondesktop");
  } else {
      $(".aboutbuttondesktop").removeClass("aboutbuttondesktop").addClass("aboutbutton");
  }
});
```

Finally you should call your resize event on-load incase the browser is *already* under/over your 900px breakpoint.

```
$(window).resize();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkx4pa0z/
Resize it to see the class change. Click it... only `.aboutbutton` is clickable.

Comment: the only thing i don't quite get is how the $("body") at the start of the event fits into this. Why are you targeting the body?

Comment: @BenLiger - because that's how [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) works. You *delegate* the work to a parent element. Here we are saying: "*listen for a click on the body, if the target of our click is an element with the class .aboutbutton then call this function*"

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to move a lot of your animation workload to css but you're concerned about providing support for IE9 users.  If I got that right, you might consider making all of you animations in css and then conditionally loading a separate javascript file as a fallback for those with browsers that don't support css transitions/transforms/animation.

Here's why:

1. It will be a whole lot easier to maintain.
2. Except in a handful of specific geographies or circumstances (i.e., if the majority of your users are in Asia or if you are building a site/application that is principally visited by business users [specifically corporate America]), the vast majority of your users will be using modern browsers.  It doesn't make much sense to penalize all site visitors with the added bloat of additional javascript or all of your desktop users with less efficient jQuery animation.
3. At some point, probably in the not too distance future, IE9 will become unimportant to you because of dwindling usage.  If you've already done the work to separate your code and animations, you only have to remove the conditional load, not refactor everything again.
4. You don't have to do anything at all on resize().  For the most part resize fires repeatedly while the resize event is happening.  It's not terribly efficient to run code on this event, so if you can avoid it, that's a plus.

One simple way to accomplish this for IE is to use conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="your-jQuery-Animation-Fallback.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This would only load the javascript file if the browser is 'lte' or less than or equal to IE 9.

If you wanted even broader coverage, you could use a library like Modernizr, and do specific feature detection and then use the built-in load method to add your jQuery fallback. Such as:

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.csstransitions, //or whatever you need support for
  nope: 'your-jQuery-Animation-Fallback.js'
});
```

This might let you support browsers like Opera-mini or older versions of Android (ca. v2.3).

Similarly, if you didn't want to use Modernizr, but still wanted to do feature-detection, you could create your own.  Notably, support for matchMedia and css transitions, transforms and animation all align very nicely.  As such, you could take advantage of that fact by using it to run a test and if it is true load your script with jQuery's $.getScript method:

```
if(typeof window.matchMedia == 'undefined') {
  $.getScript( 'your-jQuery-Animation-Fallback.js' );
};
```

I know this question has already been answered and I know I might be skewered for "not answering the question that was asked." Nonetheless, I thought is was worth sharing.

Comment: Some excellent suggestions here, thanks a lot for proposing the various methods. I think the <!--[if lte IE 9]> method would be the simplest for me to implement. Will be a lot simpler when ie9 is no longer used and people wont have to worry as much about css3 compatability!